# Unable to update an existing custom record in Visualforce

Tags: apex, visualforce

All, I have a controller that updates a visualforce page. An interaction gets created first just fine but when I try to update it the page reloads and there is no record update. I looked at the debug log and there is nothing being recorded for system.debug. Please note that inteId has a value and I even hardcoded an id for testing and nothing. I did the same for type__c just in case. I have searched the web for days and decided to seek your assistance. Can you please help?

```
public Id inteId {get;set;} 
public String selectedPrg {get;set;}    
public String selectedType {get;set;}
public String selectedDirection {get;set;}
public String selectedSubject {get;set;}   

public PageReference save() {    

   List<Interaction__c>  inteLst = new List<Interaction__c>();
   List<Interaction__c> iLst = [select Id, Program__c, Type__c, Direction__c, Subject__c from Interaction__c where Id =: inteId limit 1];        

   System.debug('The inteId: ' + inteId);
   System.debug('the selected interaction data: '+selectedPrg+'_'+selectedDirection); 

   for(Interaction__c i : iLst){                                  
     if(iLst.size()> 0){            
        i.Program__c = selectedPrg;  
        i.Type__c = 'Call'; //selectedType;
        i.Direction__c = selectedDirection;
        i.Subject__c = selectedSubject;
        inteLst.add(i);                      
     }
   }            

   try {
     update inteLst;
   }catch(Exception ex){    
      system.debug('Exception is' + ex);
      ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR,'Exception is'));
   }  
  return null;                                 
}
```

---

Example VF

```
  <div class="row">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="intesubject">Subject:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <apex:selectList id="intesubject" size="1" value="{!selectedSubject}" required="false" styleClass="form-control"> <!-- required="true" prevents the find acct from working -->   
        <apex:selectOptions value="{!Subject}"/>
        </apex:selectList>              
       <span class="help-block">
            Please select an interaction subject.
       </span>

       <br/>
           <apex:commandButton id="updateint" styleClass="btn btn-primary" action="{!save}" onclick="" value="Update" /> 
       <span class="help-block">
            Click to update the interaction.
       </span>

      </div>
  </div
```

The last thing that appears in the debug log is the "subject" picklist. There is nothing concerning the "save" action after it.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue after rebuilding the VF page little by little. It turns out that I had two tags for the form class="form-horizontal". Perhaps adding ids would have solved the problem but removing one of them the trick and everything is working. I appreciate all the help!!

```
<apex:form>

<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="#">
  <!-- page 1 of SPA -->
</form>

<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="#">
  <!-- page 2 of SPA-->
</form>

</apex:form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have made an update to your VF Controller, I cut out the reassignment of the list to a new list. See if this makes any difference:

```
public Id inteId {get;set;} 
public String selectedPrg {get;set;}    
public String selectedType {get;set;}
public String selectedDirection {get;set;}
public String selectedSubject {get;set;}   

public PageReference save() {    

    //This is not needed
   //List<Interaction__c>  inteLst = new List<Interaction__c>();
   List<Interaction__c> iLst = [select Id, Program__c, Type__c, Direction__c, Subject__c from Interaction__c where Id =: inteId limit 1];        

   System.debug('The inteId: ' + inteId);
   System.debug('the selected interaction data: '+selectedPrg+'_'+selectedDirection); 

   for(Interaction__c i : iLst){                                  
     if(iLst.size()> 0){            
        i.Program__c = selectedPrg;  
        i.Type__c = 'Call'; //selectedType;
        i.Direction__c = selectedDirection;
        i.Subject__c = selectedSubject;
        //inteLst.add(i); This is not needed
     }
   }            

   try {
     update iLst;
   }catch(Exception ex){    
      system.debug('Exception is' + ex);
      ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR,'Exception is'));
   }  
  return null;                                 
}
```

From what it seems like your Debug log is telling us, it seems as though your `save()` method is never being called. I would want to make sure your `<apex:page>` `controller` parameter is being set correctly.

Comment: Hi Bryan, thanks so much for looking into this. I tried that without results. When I click the button the page reloads and the form resets, perhaps this has something to do with it. I am not getting any errors either and the "save" PageReference is not being tracked in the debug log at all, none of it. Thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: Can you remove the try catch temporarily and just perform the `update` and see if any errors are happening at all

Comment: Done, no errors to troubleshoot : (

Comment: Can you include a picture of the debug log when you run this?

Comment: Done, see edits.

Comment: Hmm, can you include the `<apex:page>` tag in your VF code? Also can you remove the `onclick` attribute from your `commandButton`

Comment: Adding more explanation in the body of your answer would probably help OP better understand what the issue is. Right now, this answer is pretty close to being a _code dump_.

Comment: @DerekF apologies you are right, made some updates

Comment: @BryanAnderson I was able to find the issue after your request to show here the page tag. I was too focused on the apex and didn't think VF could be the issue all along. Please see the answer I posted. Gratitude for all the help! Have a great day!

Comment: @Snights great glad I was able to help in some way!